# Returning an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am an amateur in Java and I am stuck at returning and array in Java. 
Here is my program (shortened):

```
public class Mershor {

    public static int[] shotrting(int a[]) {
        //here I wrote an algorithm for shorting 
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a;
        a = new int[6];
        a[0] = 5;
        a[1] = 3;
        a[2] = 4;
        a[3] = 7;
        a[4] = 1;
        a[5] = 2;
        for (int o = 0; o <= a.length; o++) {
            System.out.println(shotrting(a[o]));    
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> The method `shotrting(int[])` in the type `Mershor` is not applicable for the arguments `(int)`

Comment: @ParkerHalo o is an int variable, so that part does work

Answer (score 3):

You are passing only integers, not array to shotrting(int[]).

To pass the entire array you type as argument the name of array: shotrting(a).

I also did some minor changes to your main program.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //shorter initialization
    int[] a = new int {5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2};

    int[] result_array=shotrting[a];

    //To print the array in a more appropriate form.
    System.out.print(java.util.Arrays.toString(result_array);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
System.out.println(shotrting(a[o]));
```

to

```
System.out.println(shotrting(a)[o]);
```

The `shotrting` takes an `array` as a parameter, not an `Integer`.

> **a = [5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2]**
>
> **a[o] = 5**.....

`shotrting(a)` returns an array. You can access its elements using the [index] notation, like `shotrting(a)[0]`, `shotrting(a)[1]`...